# How to formulate statistical hypothesis testing for a table of data

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a table where each column represents a variable and each row represents a measurement. And I have a list of "hypothesis" about the relationship of the variables. For example, one "hypothesis" is that "the value of column A is greater than the value of column B". I can easily count how many times this is true given this dataset. In this case, in 96% of the measurements, "the value of column A is greater than the value of column B". I don't have *a priori* information about the expected distribution of these variables.

My question is this: how can I formulate this problem as a statistical hypothesis testing (what test statistic could be used)? What other information I might need?

Comment: What is the relationship of the data in column A to column B? Test the distribution of the data for normality. You can do this in MS Excel using XLSTAT. If normal, calculate the mean for each column and do a t test for a difference in means. This could be a paired test depending on the relationship of the data. That is, are the corresponding values in columns A and B a measure of the same sample item. The null hypothesis would be there is no significant difference in the means and the alternate hypothesis is there is a significant difference or one is significantly greater than the other.

Comment: Each row is a set of measurements of the same sample item.

Comment: Then a paired t test is most suitable if the data are normal. There are many considerations for a valid test if you want to make reliable inferences about the result. You should read up on hypothesis testing from a reliable source. They are too numerous and extensive to go over in a comments section.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think a paired t test might be what I need (at least in the cases where columns are approximately normally distributed).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the hypotesis you want to prove cannot be the null hypothesis (see, e.g., https://www.statlect.com/glossary/null-hypothesis for a discussion of this point). For example, if you want to prove that A is greater than B on average, your null hypothesis should be that A is equal to B on average. "A greater than B" is going to be your alternative hypothesis. For example, you could use a t test to test the null that the mean of A-B=0. Given your alternative hypothesis, your t test should be one-tailed (you are excluding a priori that the mean of A-B is negative).